# Unable to get text() node before a specific span using xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm trying to find the immediate preceding text of an element.

Below is the sample HTML code that I'm working on.

```
<span class= "platform">
 ::before
 <br>
 name
 <br>
 age
 <span class = "highlight">
   ::before
   "Negine"
 </span>
</span>
```

Came up with an XPath:

```
//span[@class='platform']/text()[following-sibling::span[position() = 1]]
```

But the XPath is returning both text nodes where as it should return only 'age'.

Comment: including proper sample html snippet.

<span class = 'platform'>
  <br>
   name
  <br>
  age
  <span class = 'highlight'>
      address
  </span>
</span>

Answer (score 0):

Have written this text using your provided HTML in the comment section.

Try using this `xpath` - `//span[@class="platform"]/text()[3]`

Comment: Thanks Swaroop , but my html is dynamic new lines keep on adding and child span may change the location. 
//span[@class = 'pairRight fieldspan_WLM_CompleteSWIFTMessage_Message noLabel ']/text()[preceding-sibling::br and following::span[position() = 1]]
using above xpath i am able to return all text nodes but not the immediate preceding node of span. Please provide your thoughts.

Comment: Please share the URL or DOM. So that we can help you better.

Comment: Apologies Swaroop, here is the DOM

<span class="pairRight fieldspan_WLM_CompleteSWIFTMessage_Message noLabel ">
{1:F01ZYACSGS0XXXX0000000000}{2:I290WPACAU20XXXXN}{4:
<br>:20:PIV+TEST19
<br>:21:REF 
<span class="platformHighlighted">NEGINE SAB</span>
<br>:25:11223344
<br>:32D:200228GBP1,
<br>:52D:
<span class="platformHighlighted">NEGINE SAB</span>
<br>1 TEST ROAD ; ;AZ AZERBAIJA
<br>:71B:/CANF/GBP1
<br>//TEST 
<span class="platformHighlighted">NEGINE SAB</span>
<br>:72:TEST 
<span class="platformHighlighted">NEGINE SAB</span> 
<br>AZ AZERBAIJA
<br>
-}
</span>